# Joomla change link after login

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I am using joomla 2.5 and i am trying to redirect on my component after joomla login.

- joomla default redirect on profile page after login, i need to change this setting want to redirect on my component.

is there any setting available in joomla admin ?

can directly redirect on that link.

please help if any idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the Login module [mod_login]? Just go into the Login module under the module manager.

On the right hand side you have 'login redirection page`. You can select any page there. If your component is not in the list just create a menu for it in the Menu manager.